# Add html after variable <body

Tags: php, html, regex

My body content is always different and can have various content as:

```
<body class="wordpress y2015 m10 d23 h12 single s-y2010 s-m02" style="width: 100%;">
<body class="s-category-linux" style="background-color: red;">
```

with some html behind.

How can I add something juste behind the body closure (in PHP)

For example, how can I replace:

```
<body class="wordpress y2015 m10 d23 h12 single s-y2010 s-m02 s-d10" style="width: 100%;"><div id="wrapper"><div id="header">
```

By:

```
<body class="wordpress y2015 m10 d23 h12 single s-y2010 s-m02 s-d10" style="width: 100%;"><span class="blabla">My new html content</span><div id="wrapper"><div id="header">
```

I need a regex for preg_replace

Thanks for help !

Comment: By making a php variable that contains the body's classes and then use logic / w.e to fill the variable?

Comment: There are probably 100 ways. Show more context of your actual situation or all you are going to get are **guesses**

Comment: I just need one way ! a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial regex that works unless `>` characters might occur somewhere within the `<body>` tag itself:

Search for `<body[^>]*>` and replace the match with `$0<mynewtag>`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/<body[^>]*>/', '$0<mynewtag>', $subject);
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qQ1wI6/1).